# How to cast from double(*)(void) to a function pointer with given number of parameter?

Tags: c++, casting, void-pointers

I have a function pointer with with type `double(*)(void)` and I want to  cast it to a function with given number parameter.

```
// already have function my_func with type double(*)(void)
int para_num;
para_num = get_fun_para_num(); // para_num can be 1 or 2

if para_num == 1
    cout << static_cast<double (*)(double)>(my_func)(5.0) << endl;
else
    cout << static_cast<double (*)(double, double)>(my_func)(5.0, 3.1) << endl;
```

I can ensure that the cast is correct, is any way to do the cast without if-else?

Comment: The short answer is: no.

Comment: the answer would be the same for a type BTW.

Comment: Can I offer a `switch`?

Comment: You cannot do it without the `if-else` because your condition depends on a run-time value. If you can get the number of function parameters at compile-time, then you can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Premise that is a very unsafe way to play with pointers,
you can do it with [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast).

This is a complete example:

```
#include <iostream>

/// A "generic" function pointer.
typedef void* (*PF_Generic)(void*);  

/// Function pointer double(*)(double,double).
typedef double (*PF_2Arg)(double, double);  

/// A simple function
double sum_double(double d1, double d2) { return d1 + d2; }

/// Return a pointer to simple function in generic form
PF_Generic get_ptr_function() {
  return reinterpret_cast<PF_Generic>(sum_double);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // Get pointer to function in the "generic form"
  PF_Generic p = get_ptr_function();

  // Cast the generic pointer into the right form
  PF_2Arg p_casted = reinterpret_cast<PF_2Arg>(p);

  // Use the pointer
  std::cout << (*p_casted)(12.0, 18.0) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```